# Drawing majority ordered Newick trees using Ete3

Tags: python, tree, ete3

Is there a way to draw trees using Ete3 so that the node with the largest value is always set to the bottom? And  if there are more than two branches, nodes are in descending order. See an example below:

```
     ___1         __1
    |            | 
    |            |
__12|       ____4|      __1
    |      |     |     |
    |      |     |     |__1
    |      |     |____3|
    |      |           |__1
    |      |
    |      |                ___1
    |      |               |
    |____11|        __1    |       __1
           |       |       |_____2|
           |______7|       |      |__1
                   |       |
                   |______6|       ___1
                           |      |
                           |_____3|
                                  |      __1
                                  |____2|
                                        |__1
```

Comment: *"the node with the largest value"*: this seems to suggest you already have a tree data structure. Can you provide it in Python syntax?

Comment: Actually, what I did not realize is that the order in which the tree is drawn seems to be following the order of the Newick string itself. Thus, sorting the Newick string results in the output I wanted.